# How to debug "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression"?

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools, webpack-hot-client

Just recently I started seeing this message from several pages in my React project. I don't recall seeing it before:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2430 ./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:2430
printWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:138
handleWarnings @ webpackHotDevClient.js:143
push../node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js.connection.onmessage @ webpackHotDevClient.js:210
```

I googled it a few times but could not find a lead where the issue is coming form. Any help would be appreciated.